# Augmented Reality integrated with Android Studio - Integrate Vuforia SDK to existing android studio project

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am currently developing an app using Android Studio and I want to integrate Augmented Reality using pattern recognition. I was thinking about using Vuforia SDK, but since I can't find clear documentation about how to insert it to an android studio project I'm not sure if it's the best approach. Does someone know how to do it or have any alternatives to do what I want to?